# nvd3 line chart issue

Tags: javascript, css, charts, nvd3.js

[image: nvd3 line chart with CSS issues]

Here, I have used line chart from nvd3. I am trying to fix a few issues with this chart
1. This is an interactive chart, but even if i hover over a point where there are no points from the data, it still shows up the x and y-points.
2. x-axis and y-axis lines do NOT show up. Also the interactive guide doesn't come up in a rectangular box outlined.
3. The x-axis gets cut off at the end (see 14:29:19 being cut off at the end) no matter how much i increase the width to.
4. I am trying to remove the fill that we see above the line graph but styling changes made by me resulted in no success.

code that i use to fetch the line chart

```
var redraw = function(testData) {
    var dataT = [{
        key : 'Character Count',
        values : testData,
        color : '#00AEEF',
        area : false
    }];

    var margin = {
        top : 80,
        right : 20,
        bottom : 80,
        left : 50
    }, width = 1000 - (margin.left + margin.right), height = 600 - (margin.top + margin.bottom), x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]), y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    x.domain(d3.extent(dataT[0].values, function(d) {
        return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d.TimeStamp));
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataT[0].values, function(d) {
        return d.CharCount;
    })]);

    nv.addGraph(function() {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart().transitionDuration(350).useInteractiveGuideline(true)
            .showLegend(true).showYAxis(true).showXAxis(true).x(function(d) {
                return new Date(d.TimeStamp);
            }).y(function(d) {
                return d.CharCount;
            });

        chart.xAxis.axisLabel('Time').tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%X')(new Date(d));
        }).scale(x).orient("bottom");

        chart.yAxis.axisLabel('Character Count').tickFormat(d3.format(',')).scale(y);

        chart.lines.forceY([0]);

        d3.select('#chart2 svg')//.append("g")
        .datum(dataT).attr('height', height).attr('width', width).call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        return chart;
    });
};
```

redraw(data)--data fetched froma  service ith dateTimeStamp in x-axis and integer in y-axis points.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. This is an interactive chart, but even if i hover over a point where there are no points from the data, it still shows up the x and
>      y-points. 2. x-axis and y-axis lines do NOT show up. Also the
>      interactive guide doesn't come up in a rectangular box outlined.

Adding corresponding javascript file in nvd3 zip file should solve the problem(line.js, linechart.js and corresponding css file)

> 3.The x-axis gets cut off at the end (see 14:29:19 being cut off at the end) no matter how much i increase the width to.

This is because you have not set the width and height of the chart in your codes to generate the chart
you should do

`chart.width(width).height(height)`

> 4.I am trying to remove the fill that we see above the line graph but styling changes made by me resulted in no success

This I am not sure how to solve as I do not have your dataset, so I not able to reproduce the problem

[Here is my test code](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=cf0fb05dffcf3740&id=CF0FB05DFFCF3740!110&ithint=file,.rar&authkey=!AEBVv39dXpSj59U)